# Firebase limits me to set my database to one region permanently, how do I serve people from other regions with low latency?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I have set the location of my Firestore database to asia-south-1, let suppose now I start getting users from the US as well as from India, how will I serve both the groups with lower latency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the properties of your project once it's set up, nor even simply pay more for better service.  If you want improved service in different [regions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones), you will need to buy computing resources in each of those regions.  This requires setting up multiple projects, with each Firestore product [configured](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) for the region you want improved service.  Note that not all Firebase and GCP products are available in all regions.

If you want all users in all regions to be using the same set of data with improved latency, that's not possible to configure.  You will have to build a way to mirror data between the different projects.  There is nothing terribly easy about that, nor are there any existing solutions offered by Firebase or GCP to do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Doug nailed it for Firestore. So

Note that Firebase's Realtime Database (unlike Firestore) can have multiple databases per project, which means you can set up a database instances in each region (it support three right now) and redirect your user's traffic to the region closest to them. You may still have to replicate data between the database instances, similar to Doug's answer, but (unlike in Doug's answer) with Realtime Database this can happen within a single project.